How to display the last date modified information of each file
I want to find that files exist or not via powershell. I want to display the last date modified information of each file right next to it. how can I do this?
my output:
File exists. Date: C-00000291-00000000-00000036.sys C-00000291-00000000-00000066.sys 07/19/2024 11:46:10 07/19/2024 11:46:22

my desired output:
File exists. C-00000291-00000000-00000036.sys Date: 07/19/2024 11:46:10 C-00000291-00000000-00000066.sys Date: 07/19/2024 11:46:22

script:
if (Test-Path  "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*" -PathType Leaf) {
    $lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*").LastWriteTime
    $Name = (Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*").Name
    Write-Output "File exists. $Name Date: $lastModifiedDate" 
} else {
    Write-Output "File does not exist."
}


Call Get-Item once, then iterate over the resulting files to produce the details for each:
if (Test-Path  "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*" -PathType Leaf) {
    $fileDetails = @(Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*" |ForEach-Object { 
      '{0} Date: {1:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}' -f $_.Name,$_.LastWriteTime
    }) -join ' '
    Write-Output "File exists. ${fileDetails}" 
} else {
    Write-Output "File does not exist."
}


$Directory = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike"
$Filter = 'C-00000291*'


# dynamically add the wildcard at the end of the directory name.   
# this way you do not have to bother wondering how the directory path is written.   
$TestDirectory = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath '*'

# check if there is AT LEAST one File in the directory matching the Filter
if (Test-Path -Path $TestDirectory -Filter $Filter -PathType Leaf) {
    
    # Get all Files in the directory, filtered.  
    # Add a string containing file Name and last time the file was written to $FileList array.   
    $FileList = Get-ChildItem -file -LiteralPath $Directory -Filter $Filter | 
        ForEach-Object { "{0} Date: {1}" -f $_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') }

    # return the array, merged as a single string with elements separated by one space.  
    # prepend it with static declatration of file existing.    
    'File Exists. ' + $FileList -join ' '


}
else {
    "No File matching '$Filter' in directory '$Directory"
}

As a MUCH EASIER TO READ alternative, you can declare the existance of the files once and the one line with Name\Date for each file.
if (Test-Path -Path $TestDirectory -Filter $Filter -PathType Leaf) {
    'File Exists. '
    Get-ChildItem -file -LiteralPath $Directory -Filter $Filter | 
        ForEach-Object { "File Exists. {0} Date: {1}" -f $_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') }
}
else {
    "No File matching '$Filter' in directory '$Directory"
}

